# How do I achieve a hover over image effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, css

I'm trying to achieve the same mouse over image effect seen on [wookmark](http://www.wookmark.com/) and I'm assuming this is done with some jquery and css magic.  Are there any good tutorials that show how this is done?

Looking through the jquery docs it seems I would need to use hover like so:

```
$("li.preview").hover(function(e){  
    // show and hide come css magic
});
```

Not sure where to go with the CSS portion of it...

Comment: Looks home grown. Modernizr and http://www.wookmark.com/js/tiles.js. Have a look at qtip2 or something better since I see heavy iPad support

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a wrapper around your image(s) and inside that wrapper you can have the buttons you want to appear/disappear on hover. Then just show/hide those buttons when the image is hovered.

HTML --

```
<span class="image-wrapper">
    <span class="image-options"></span>
    <img src="..." />
</span>
```

CSS --

```
.image-wrapper {
    position : relative;
    display  : inline-block;
}
.image-wrapper .image-options {
    position : absolute;
    top      : 0;
    right    : 0;
    left     : 0;
    height   : 25px;
    z-index  : 2;
    display  : none;
}
.image-wrapper:hover .image-options {
    display : block;
}
```

You can also use CSS3 to fade-in/out the options element:

```
.image-wrapper {
    position : relative;
    display  : inline-block;
}
.image-wrapper img {
    position : relative;
}
.image-wrapper .image-options {
    position : absolute;
    top      : 0;
    right    : 0;
    left     : 0;
    height   : 25px;
    z-index  : 2;
    background         : grey;
    border             : 1px solid black;
    opacity            : 0;
    filter             : alpha(opacity=0);
    -webkit-transition : opacity 0.25s linear;
    -moz-transition    : opacity 0.25s linear;
    -ms-transition     : opacity 0.25s linear;
    -o-transition      : opacity 0.25s linear;
    transition         : opacity 0.25s linear;
}
.image-wrapper:hover .image-options {
    opacity            : 1;
    filter             : alpha(opacity=100);
}​
```

Here is a demo using only CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/fJsJb/

And of-course you can make the fade happen with JS:

```
$('.image-wrapper').on('mouseenter', function () {
    $(this).children('.image-options').stop().fadeIn(250);
}).on('mouseleave', function () {
    $(this).children('.image-options').stop().fadeOut(250);
});
```

Here is a demo using JS: http://jsfiddle.net/fJsJb/1/

**UPDATE**

You can also create a slide animation by animating the `top` property like this:

```
.image-wrapper {
    position : relative;
    display  : inline-block;
    overflow : hidden;
}
.image-wrapper img {
    position : relative;
}
.image-wrapper .image-options {
    position : absolute;
    top      : -25px;
    right    : 0;
    left     : 0;
    height   : 25px;
    z-index  : 2;
    background         : grey;
    border             : 1px solid black;
    -webkit-transition : top 0.25s linear;
    -moz-transition    : top 0.25s linear;
    -ms-transition     : top 0.25s linear;
    -o-transition      : top 0.25s linear;
    transition         : top 0.25s linear;
}
.image-wrapper:hover .image-options {
    top : 0;
}​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fJsJb/2/

Comment: +1. I didn't know about the "transition" property of CSS. FWIW, the CSS-only solution doesn't work in IE 7. Also, the JS version *should* work in IE 7 but is complaining about 'console' being undefined. Any thoughts?

Comment: @ErikE It works in IE7 for me, but you may need to add `*display : inline` to the `.image-wrapper` CSS rule so it will be compatible with IE7's crappy CSS rendering.

Comment: Thanks so much for the great example. The CSS option seems like it'll work.

Comment: @Paul I like the CSS implementation too, the thing to keep in mind is that the animation won't work for browsers that don't support the `transition` property: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions, the element will display, but not with an animation.

Comment: Ahh, and I see IE 9 won't support it util v10 so I may use your JS example instead.  I did have one more question.  To create the individual buttons like in the posted example, I assume these are simply part of the image-wrapper correct?

Comment: @Paul Specifically I called the button-holding-element `.image-options`. So put your buttons in that element and change it's CSS to look like you want.

Comment: All I get with the CSS version in IE 7 is a black-border, white-background rectangle appearing behind the image, extending to the right of the image by some distance. All I get with the JS version in IE 7 is a script error about 'console'.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with css like this.

```
<style>
.imageBox { float:left; width:100px; height:100px; position:relative; background:#000; overflow:hidden; }
.imageBox .imageActions { position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:40px; background:#999; display:none; }
.imageBox img { width:100%; }
.imageBox:hover .imageActions { display:block; }
</style>

<div class="imageBox">
    <div class="imageActions "></div>
    <img src=".." />
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ztGwx/)